# Usage of “bald … bald”

Tags: conjunction

This is mainly found in formal writing. *Bald* is immediately followed by the verb in both clauses:

> ***Bald*** weinte das Baby, ***bald*** lachte es.

Is there another way to say *bald … bald*?

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***(manch)mal*** for instance:

> ***M(anchm)al*** weinte das Baby, ***(manch)mal*** lachte es

Answer (score 2):

marsze already pointed out in the other answer that you can replace it with *mal*. So the technical meaning of it is

> At times ... at other times...

However, there is a reason for using this *bald* instead of *mal* because it makes the changes feel quicker, more sudden.

> Manchmal weinte das Baby, manchmal lachte es.

This is really just a description of the reality of babies.

> Mal lachte es, mal weinte es.

This already sounds a little bit like a moody baby. It could be an answer to the question:

> How did the baby react when you gave him his toy pony.

And then finally:

> Bald lachte es, bald weinte es.

This is even more moody since it sounds a bit like there isn't really a specific reason anymore. You're in the room, it laughs, 10 minutes later it cries.